# rotate and then merge two images with Imagemagick 7.0.4-3-Q16

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to rotate a pair of images, one 90 and one -90, and then stitch them horizontally. I can do both separately, but for reasons I don't understand the following falls over:

```
magick montage (magick convert "J:\img1.jpg" -rotate 90) (magick convert "J:\img2.jpg" -rotate -90) -geometry +0+0 "J:\imgout.jpg"
```

I get the error:

```
convert:  `90' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3251.
```

Removing the `magick convert` parts gives a different error:

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be easier:

```
convert 1.png -rotate 90 2.png -rotate -90 +append result.png
```

As @Bonzo suggests, if running ImageMagick v7+, replace `convert` with `magick`:

```
magick 1.png -rotate 90 2.png -rotate -90 +append result.png
```

Given `1.png` and `2.png`:

[image]

[image]

You will get

[image]

Comment: Just beat me to it Mark. Also on version 7 I would replace convert with magick

Comment: @Bonzo Yes, I must try and remember - my old habits die hard but `magick` definitely is preferable for Windows users where ImageMagick `convert` used to clash with Microsoft's `CONVERT.EXE` for converting filesystems.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this still gives the following error: You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator. It points to the character starting the second -rotate. This is on a Windows 7 machine through Powershell by the way. (cmd is refusing to recognise the particular drive but that's another issue)

Comment: You probably have to escape the parentheses (brackets) differently or not at all in Windows. Try without backslashes, or with caret in front `^(` and  `^)`

Comment: I'm getting the same error with carets and no escape characters.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Windows. Some people suggest a backtick as an escape character, some people say to use `--%` as the first argument after `magick` to stop meta characters being interpreted. Make sure you have spaces around the parentheses (brackets) too.

Comment: The parenthesis are not necessary in my test. It works without them. I'm editing the answer to remove them. If they were (or for unknown reasons are for some folks) necessary, however, the escape sequences in CMD for parenthesis are `^(` and `^)`

Comment: The parenthesis is necessary to not apply the rotation to the first image twice, first rotating it 90 degrees, then rotating it -90 back (tested with ImageMagick 7.0.11-13 Q16 x64 2021-05-17). 
In Powershell Mark's suggestion is correct, so the command is: 
`magick --% 1.png -rotate 90 ( 2.png -rotate -90 ) +append result.png`